# How can i install pygobject from my distribution package. And install all the required headers for cairo and probably GTK

Tags: python, linux, centos7, cairo, tryton

```
when i run the command i have this error message
$gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $ pip3 install --user --upgrade gnuhealth-client
```

Package cairo-gobject was not found in the pkg-config search path.

```
 Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo-gobject.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'cairo-gobject' found
  Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo-gobject >= 0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
Failed to build PyGObject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Can you try to remove ~/.cache/pip, reinstall PyGObject in new environment and check if this error still comes

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing, but did you try asking Google? There seems to be a cairo-gobject package for centos. For example, https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/cairo-gobject-1.15.12-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html looks pretty official.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the [Getting Started with PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#getting-started) instructions.

Are you using Ubuntu? You didn't say what your distribution is.

If so, to install PyGObject run:

```
sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```